# How to Control an Activity's Contents from a Service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, communication, listener

I am new to Android

Can anyone provide an example/help on this.

For example having a TextView's contents on an Activity automatically changed by a Service.

I already managed to get the service running, is there a listener I could use on the Activity class?

please please please provide examples with answers

Comment: something like the onActivityResult override but for Services

Comment: There are extensive examples on how to communicate with a Service in the service documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html Did you read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZiGi

Have a look at [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

  private TextView textView;

  public String getTextView(){
    return textView;
  }
  public void setTextView(TextView textView){
    this.textView = textView;
  }
}

class MyActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApplication myApp = ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext());
    TextView textview = myApp.getTextView();
    ...
  }
}
```

Set global resources(that will be used in whole Application Context including Services) in above manner & you are done!

Comment: hi brotha, thanks for the quick reply, what i actually need is something to trigger some lines of code on the activity, like a listener, something like the onActivityResult for sub activities but for services

Comment: @ZiGi the hack for what you want to get done is put a thread in the Activity that keeps checking that variable(global variable as I mentioned in the code above) & run that method (or your piece of code).   Though the official way of communicating between the activity and the service is binding them (which I believe is a tough job. atleast for me!) check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onBind(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Also check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent) .It too could prove helpful.You can set intent data to activity and put your code in onNewIntent

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the EarthQuakeViewer samples.
http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html